# What does that syntax mean?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, v-data-table

i am working with vuetify and i need to make the serverside controlled data tables run.
now i saw this piece of code in the docs right [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#server-side-paginate-and-sort)

and apart from that i am struggeling to understand how this is working i am confiused on this very piece of code.

a object with no keys gets override by `this.options`
but `this.options` is empty anyway, u can see in the docs.

```js
data () {
      return {
        totalDesserts: 0,
        desserts: [],
        loading: true,
        options: {}, //<--------------------- HERE
        headers: [
          {
            text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
            align: 'start',
            sortable: false,
            value: 'name',
          },
          { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
          { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
          { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
          { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
          { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
        ],
      }
    },
```

```js
const { sortBy, sortDesc, page, itemsPerPage } = this.options
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).  This:

```js
const { sortBy, sortDesc, page, itemsPerPage } = this.options
```

is the same as this:

```js
const sortBy = this.options.sortBy;
const sortDesc = this.options.sortDesc;
// etc.
```

If you are asking where `this.options` gets its values, it's from the template's `.sync` modifier here:

```html
<v-data-table
    ...
    :options.sync="options"
    ...
  ></v-data-table>
```

The `v-data-table` emits an event containing option data when options are set, even default options.  The `.sync` modifier then updates the binding `this.options` with the emitted option data.

Here's a [shorter version](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/5vane38t/) of the demo you linked showing this (check the console)